# MySQL performance issue on a simple two tables joined Query

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join

I'm facing a performance issue on **MySQL** and I'm unable to understand where I'm wrong. The machine runs MySQLServer 5.7.15 with two *Xeon 64bit Processors* and *8GBytes* of RAM. 
I've got two tables:

Table *data_raw* contains several fields (see *VRMS0*,*VRMS1*,*VRMS2*,*PWRA0*,*PWRA1*,*PWRA2*)

describing the voltages and active powers acquired from complicated instrumentation **every 30 seconds** from several probes on the field, each probe is uniquely identified by its *DEVICE_ID*.

Table *data_timeslot* contains few fields and is used to keep trace of when the single data_raw record was sent (see *SRV_TIMESTAMP* field)

and from which device (see *DEVICE_ID* field).

Each table contains about **7.800.000 records**.
The two tables are joined using a **PK** on **ID** (auto-increment) on **data_timeslot** and a *PK* on *TIMESLOT_ID* (auto-increment) on **data_timeslot**.
Here is the query:

```
 SELECT D.VRMS0,D.VRMS1,D.VRMS2,D.PWRA0,D.PWRA1,D.PWRA2,T.DEVICE_ID, T.SRV_TIMESTAMP 
 FROM data_raw AS D FORCE INDEX(PRIMARY) 
 INNER JOIN data_timeslots AS T ON T.ID=D.TIMESLOT_ID 
 WHERE T.DEVICE_ID='CEC02' 
 ORDER BY T.ID DESC LIMIT 1
```

The query takes always 10 seconds while the same query on a single table takes few milliseconds. 
In other words the query

```
SELECT * FROM 'data_raw' order by TIMESLOT_ID desc limit 1
```

takes just 0.0071 sec and the query

```
SELECT * FROM 'data_timeslots' order by ID desc limit 1
```

takes just 0.0042 sec so I'm wondering why the join takes so long.

Where is the bottleneck?

P.S. The 'extend' shows that the DB is using properly the PK for the operation.
Below the extend printout:

`EXPLAIN SELECT D.VRMS0,D.VRMS1,D.VRMS2,D.PWRA0,D.PWRA1,D.PWRA2,T.DEVICE_ID, T.SRV_TIMESTAMP FROM data_raw AS D INNER JOIN data_timeslots AS T ON T.ID=D.TIMESLOT_ID WHERE T.DEVICE_ID='XXXXX' ORDER BY T.ID ASC LIMIT 1

---

1   SIMPLE  T       index   PRIMARY,PK_CLUSTER_T,DEVICE_ID  PRIMARY 8       30  3.23    Using where

---

1   SIMPLE  D       eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 8   splc_smartpwr.T.ID  1   100.00      NULL`

**UPDATE** (suggested by @Alberto_Delgado_Roda): if I use *ASC LIMIT 1* the query takes just 0,0261 sec

Comment: You need an index on `DEVICE_ID` (and `timeslot_id`, but that you are already using).

Comment: Please include an explain plan for the 2 table query.  What columns are indexed in each table? Why are you forcing index primary? What happens if you don't do that?

Comment: @Used_By_Already : FORCE INDEX was just an attempt to solve the issue. If I don't use it the result is the same (as the Primary Key was already used). Above the explain text result

Comment: @Solarflare: on data_timestamps there are already indexes on ID (PKey), on DEVICE_ID, on SRV_TIMESTAMP and a covering index on both DEVICE_ID+SRV_TIMESTAMP (Cluster Index). On data_raw the only possible index is in TIMESLOT_ID

Comment: Try forcing the index on `DEVICE_ID`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reply to "why"

Data_timeslots has a clusteted index that suits the ascending order

*How the Clustered Index Speeds Up Queries*

Accessing a row through the clustered index is fast because the index search leads directly to the page with all the row data. If a table is large, the clustered index architecture often saves a disk I/O operation when compared to storage organizations that store row data using a different page from the index record. (For example, MyISAM uses one file for data rows and another for index records.)

See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-index-types.html

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

1: What happen if do you replace INNER JOIN for STRAIGHT_JOIN?

```
 SELECT D.VRMS0,D.VRMS1,D.VRMS2,D.PWRA0,D.PWRA1,D.PWRA2,T.DEVICE_ID, T.SRV_TIMESTAMP 
 FROM data_raw AS D FORCE INDEX(PRIMARY) 
 STRAIGHT_JOIN data_timeslots AS T ON T.ID=D.TIMESLOT_ID 
 WHERE T.DEVICE_ID='CEC02' 
 ORDER BY T.ID DESC LIMIT 1
```

2. What happen if do you replace DESC LIMIT 1 for ASC LIMIT 1?

Comment: STRAIGHT_JOIN takes even longer (102 seconds)
ASC LIMIT 1 is incredibly faster 0.0139 sec ... why?

Answer (score 0):

I just figured out that the query:
`SELECT T.ID,T.DEVICE_ID, T.SRV_TIMESTAMP, D.VRMS0,D.VRMS1,D.VRMS2,D.PWRA0,D.PWRA1,D.PWRA2 FROM data_timeslots as T INNER JOIN data_raw AS D ON D.TIMESLOT_ID=T.ID ORDER BY T.ID DESC LIMIT 1` 
runs in **just 0.0174 sec** as expected. **I just reversed the order in the SELECT statement and the result changed dramatically**. The question now is why???

Comment: Check the explain. You also changed the order of your joins. Maybe it uses the index on `device_id` now? And, just to make sure: you are using InnoDB?

Comment: @Solarflare: Yes I'm using InnoDB. I guess that changing the order of the join somehow changed the index used as well. However I'm confused: why changing the order in the select and the order of the join makes so big difference? I was not expecting that.

Comment: Did you check if it changed the index? Actually it might be the missing `where` that changed the execution time (it can use the primary keys to efficiently join, without the index on `device_id`).

Comment: @Solarflare: I guess you're right.
1 SIMPLE T  ref DEVICE_ID DEVICE_ID 15 const 248840 100.00 Using where 
1 SIMPLE D  eq_ref PRIMARY PRIMARY 8 splc_smartpwr.T.ID 1 100.00 Null

Comment: Well, `devide_id` is the correct index when you include your `where` (otherwise it's not). If MySQL doesn't take it, use `force`. It sometimes takes the wrong execution plan, why exactly I don't know (can be old statistics, or it got tricked by the `force index` for `data_raw` to take the index that is used for the join on the joined table too).

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server? (Don't tag products not involved.)

Comment: Removed mssql tag as there is way too much evidence that this question is mysql related. Please don't include tags that are not relevant to the question.

Comment: @jarlh: I'm using MySQL and I haven't tagged MSSQL. Maybe I mistyped it. Thanks for having removed it.